# Creating line graph without library in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making some data visualator for my project. I'm now trying and line graphs but i can make until somewhere. I wondering how i can add texts or hover like functions the code?

My Last Code:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const datas = [
      {
        value: 10
      },
      {
        value: 15
      },
      {
        value: 5
      },
      {
        value: 7.5
      },
      {
        value: 1
      }
    ]
    
    const minimum = datas.reduce(
      (acc, loc) =>
        acc.value < loc.value
          ? acc
          : loc
    )
    const maximum = datas.reduce(
      (acc, loc) =>
        acc.value > loc.value
          ? acc
          : loc
    )
    const c = document.getElementById("canvas")
    
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    datas.forEach((data,i) => {
      lasty = (c.height - Math.floor(data.value / maximum.value * c.height))
      lastx = Math.floor(c.width / datas.length) * i
      ctx.lineTo(lastx,lasty)
    })
    ctx.stroke();
  },10)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ctx.fillText(string, x, y) function.

[More about ctx.filletxt](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp)

Like that?

Remark: I moved the ctx.moveTo(0,0) line into the loop that removes your first vrtical line:
i === 0 && ctx.moveTo(lastx, lasty);

```js
window.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const datas = [
      {
        value: 10,
      },
      {
        value: 15,
      },
      {
        value: 5,
      },
      {
        value: 7.5,
      },
      {
        value: 1,
      },
    ];

    const minimum = datas.reduce((acc, loc) =>
      acc.value < loc.value ? acc : loc
    );
    const maximum = datas.reduce((acc, loc) =>
      acc.value > loc.value ? acc : loc
    );
    const c = document.getElementById("canvas");

    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    datas.forEach((data, i) => {
      lasty = c.height - Math.floor((data.value / maximum.value) * c.height);
      lastx = Math.floor(c.width / datas.length) * i;
      i === 0 && ctx.moveTo(lastx, lasty);
      ctx.lineTo(lastx, lasty);
      ctx.fillText(data.value, lastx + 15, lasty + 10);
    });
    ctx.stroke();
  }, 10);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```